# An undefined term in it's first derivative of the function

Tags: calculus

Consider a funtion
$$f(x) = x^{n-1}e^{-x}(n-x)$$
where n $\in \mathbb{N}$.
It's derivative is :
$$f'(x) = (n-1)(n-x)x^{n-2}e^{-x}-x^{n-1}e^{-x}(n-x)-x^{n-1}e^{-x}$$

Let's take $n = 2$ and $x = 0$, the first term of $f'(x)$ is undefined.

My question is: Is the function $f'(0)$ still defined when $n = 2$ ? and why is that?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n=2$, you have that $ f'(x) = e^{-x} \left(x^2-4 x+2\right)$. So, in this case, $f'(0) = 2$. Why do you think it is undefined? Don't confuse the kind of $0^0$ you get in your expression with an indetermination.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I assume you mean if 0^0 occurs only "within limits", the convention is to treat it as 0^0 = 1, but in a normal situation, it is not defined. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JohnQ When $n=2$ the term $x^{n-1}=x$ and its derivative is the constant function $1$. There is no limit or any convention that needs to be invoked here if $0^0=1$ worries you (which it shouldn't).

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you so much, I'm being such idiot, i get it now, thank you.